# Action when element is off screen again with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I found this script that'll automatically play a video when the element is in the viewport

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#youtube-player-container').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+600) {
            $('#youtube-player-container').tubeplayer("play");
        }
    });
});
```

This works great, but I'd also like to pause the video again when it is no longer on screen. What would I need to edit/add to achieve this?

EDIT: I know there is an action 'tubeplayer("pause") available, I just don't know how to activate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very nice function to determine if your element is in the viewport 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433)

```
function isElementInViewport (el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}
```

in total:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $('.youtube-player-container').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var el = $this.get(0);
        if (isElementInViewport(el)) {
            $this.tubeplayer("play");
        } else {
            $this.tubeplayer("stop");
        }       
    })

})
```

PS: **id** is a uniquer selector I assume you meant to type '.youtube-player-container'

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! (Although it was an id, so #youtube-player-container was correct :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
//this version uses a class instead of an ID
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('.youtube-player-container').each(function(){
var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+600) {
        $(this).tubeplayer("play");
    }else{
        $(this).tubeplayer("pause");
    }
});
});
```

or

```
//use this one if you are using an ID, but double check this because I wrote it in a hurry.
$(window).scroll(function() {
var videoPos = $('#youtube-player-container')offset().top;
var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (videoPos < topOfWindow+600) {
        $('#youtube-player-container').tubeplayer("play");
    }else{
        $('#youtube-player-container').tubeplayer("pause");
    }
});
//double check my blocks, I might not have kept them balanced. I was in a hurry.
```

Comment: The reson I changed the selector to `this` is to prevent all videos on the page from starting and stopping at once.

Comment: iterating through ids is a bad practice, I suppose the op meant to use a class

Comment: This did not work. It pauses again when I scroll UP, but if I scroll further down it keeps playing.